# Shortcuts do not work on android studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently installed android studio after long time using eclipse

I have properly configured the ide and it works, but I have a problem with keyboard shortcuts.

I have setup shortcuts that comes by default and, for example, want to collapse or expand all code, this is the shortcut:

[image]

However, using that shortcut creates a comment in my code.

```
/ ** /
```

I looking setup, see the shortcut is correct:

[image]

This happens to me most keyboard shortcuts, tried different ways but do not know how to work properly.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Which keyboard layout is configured in your operating system?

Comment: @yole What do you mean exactly?

Comment: In Mac OS X, in System Preferences | Keyboard | Input Sources, what is the selected keyboard layout?

Comment: @yole Ah!, ok. is selected : Spanish ISO , which is my physical keyboard.